# How to query multiple tables with ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am trying to figure out how to write the equivalent of this query in ActiveRecord:

```
SELECT id FROM projects, neighborhoods
WHERE ST_WITHIN(projects.lonlat, neighorhoods.the_geom);
```

I tried several approaches, including

```
Neighborhood.select(:id).from('projects').where("ST_WITHIN(projects.lonlat, neighorhoods.the_geom)")
```

But the resulting query always resolves to a single table. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of the amazing tool [scuttle.io to](http://www.scuttle.io/) covert SQL to Arel:

```
Neighborhood.select(:id).where(
  Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
    'ST_WITHIN', [
      Project.arel_table[:lonlat], Neighorhood.arel_table[:the_geom]
    ]
  )
)
```